# What wrong with my cactus

Tags: diseases, cactus

[image]Ive had this cactus which i think is a Pachycereus Schotti/Monstrosus since years and its been growing fabulous. Ive just recently noticed it acquired some brown scales (non Insect) and looks like theres something wrong. Could it be from some chemical reaction? I did spray some Neem oil on several plants around it?? I loved this cactus and would hate to see it die.
Help! Thanks!

Comment: Scales is not good, can you make a picture of the situation to be sure of what's going on there?

Comment: Just sent one with the scales.

Comment: Could be bacterial or fungal infection, but I am not sure. Could you tell more about its environment? Is it grown outside? What climate? Are there other plants next to it? I am not a expert in cactus diseases, but I hope someone can help you here on this site.

Comment: Firstly, it's not a P. schottii monstrose. Those are spineless. It looks like a Cereus peruvianus monstrose.

Comment: As far as the damage is concerned, assuming there hasn't been any recent frosts, this looks like environmental damage. Neem oil doesn't seem likely. Was the neem oil diluted? Is the damage equal all around or is it only on one side? Whatever it is, the cactus probably won't die, but it will never look the same. Cover the soil and rinse the plant thoroughly in case whatever burned it is still present. You don't want the rinse water going into the soil.

Comment: thanks for your comment Ben, its a direct sun exposed plant and brought under shelter in winter. Climate is hot with temp reaching 38-40C summer and 3C winter. Location is Amman - Jordan. As were in a desert climate summer temp dip to 18 at night! So lots of fluctuation.

Comment: Tim your absolutely spot on, thanks for the correction! Neem was diluted to 0.5%, and damage is on one side. Thats a clever idea covering the soil when rinsing, ill be doing that this weekend ! Thanks for your input.

Comment: If damage is only on one side, it might be sunburn as well.

Comment: Could be benn, Ive moved it to a less direct spot and ill keep you posted on the developments, thanks y'all.